# How to replace ' character in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a text box where the user must enter a text, I want to make a control on the input (ie replace the character `'` and `'` by another character or delete it from the text entered by the user.

I tried with `textbox.TrimEnd()` or `textbox.Replace(', abc)` but I get no results

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: i don't know how to do it !!

Comment: It really would help if you told us [why you want to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: Are you doing this to prevent SQL issues? Then you **should** be using parameters instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

string.Replace() should have strings as arguments.

This will not work:

`textbox.replace(',abc)`

As the character `'` is not a string or even a character as far as the interpreter is concerned. And of course, if `abc` is a string variable you may use `abc`.

Try instead:

`textbox.text.Replace("'", "abc")`

Note the ‘.text’ so you can access the text in what I’m assuming to be a textbox object with a text property.

Comment: More likely, your successful code will look like `textbox.Text.Replace("'", "abc");`.  I can't see what your code looks like, but I'm assuming "textbox" is a control and not a string.

Comment: *string.Replace() should have strings as arguments.* Nope, String.Replace has overloaded method: `Replace(Char, Char)`

Comment: @Luthfay Yes you're correct. I should have not assumed he would want to work with strings only.

Comment: i used textbox.text.replace("'","&") and it's work perfectly , thank you for all

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use

textbox.Replace("'", "new value")
Iwish this help you brother